# How to generate all possible outcome for if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I have this if statement and I want to make all the possible outcomes.

```
if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
if (cuisine != '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
if (cuisine != '' && area != '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
if (cuisine != '' && area != '' && city != '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
if (cuisine != '' && area != '' && city != '' && minprice != '' && maxprice == ''){}
if (cuisine != '' && area != '' && city != '' && minprice != '' && maxprice != ''){}
```

etc... etc...

Comment: You are looking for a [truth table](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+truth+table+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a coding version of the [truth table](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+truth+table+site:stackoverflow.com)

```js
const conditions = {
  "cuisine": '',
  "area": '',
  "city": '',
  "minprice": '',
  "maxprice": ''
}
const arr = Object.keys(conditions),
 n = arr.length,
  m = 1 << n,
table = Array.from({length: m}).map((_,i) => {
  let s = i.toString(2); // convert to binary
  let len = n + 1 - s.length
  s = Array.from({length:len}).join('0') + s; // pad with zeroes
  return `if (${s.split('').map((bit,j) => `${arr[j]}${bit==="1"?' == ':' != '}''`).join(' && ')}) {...}`;
})

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = `     ${table.sort().join('\nelse ')}`
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the all the possible outcomes

```
              if(cuisine == '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine == '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area == '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city == '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice == '' && maxprice !== ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice == ''){}
        else if (cuisine !== '' && area !== '' && city !== '' && minprice !== '' && maxprice !== ''){}
```

There are 5 varing things that have two possible outcomes(empty or not empty)
Therefore there are 2x2x2x2x2 possibilities.

Comment: minprice and maxprice values dont change but just the == and != does

Comment: i edited it and that should make it clearer

Comment: @VaradirekSethichaiyen, I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks! but how do you do it? Manually or a generator or a ascript?

Comment: It's a pattern if you look closely.

Comment: @VaradirekSethichaiyen, check the updated answer

Comment: Seems like a waste of typing